# How to Implement Contact Call Button in setOnItemLongClickListener?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-phone-call

> I want to implement a Call A Number Button in My App, How Can I Do that?

```
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

        //Alert dialog to display options of update and delete

        final CharSequence [] items = {"Update","Delete","Call"};
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordListActivity.this);

        dialog.setTitle("Choose an Action");

        dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if(i == 0){
                    //update
                    Cursor c = MainActivity.mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM RECORD");
                    ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    while(c.moveToNext() ){
                        arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                    }
                    //Show update Dialog
                    showDialogUpdate(RecordListActivity.this,arrID.get(position));
                }
                if(i==1){
                        //delete
                    Cursor c = MainActivity.mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM RECORD");
                    ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                    while(c.moveToNext()){
                        arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                    }
                    showDialogDelete(arrID.get(position));
                }
                 if(i==3){
               //Call Method, I don't know how to do that, cause I already use a Model, I don't know how to do that.



          }

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

> I am new to Android, How to make a contact call in setOnItemLongClickListener().from the top I added my setOnItemLongClickListener method to how can I implement with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you want to know how to make a call by number?

This code for your project and it will open a call app with phone number:

```
TextView tvPhone = view.findViewById(R.id.textphone);
String phone = tvPhone.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Phone)

Comment: bro, I did this trial too.  but this is not what I wanted to look for. When I insert my name and number to SQLite Database it shows in the listview and I want to call from that listview. I have attached my GitHub project link which is "SaveContactBySQLite". can you check it?

Comment: @imtiazeemel Can you explain what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Wanted to make Call Button Work for my inserted Database where ( name, PhoneNumber).  when I click that button it will call (Phone Call) the inserted number. I hope I can explain it properly.  if you check my GitHub project I hope you will understand properly with my answer.

Comment: @imtiazeemel I watched GitHub. Please try pasting my edited code from my answer. I get phone from view and use baseContext for startActivity

Comment: Can you see my answer? where I am wrong? can you tell me? And the Error is : cannot find symbol
                            String phone = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textphone).getText();

Comment: I add this but the call button is not working ,  String phone = view.findViewById(R.id.textphone).toString();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
                            getBaseContext().startActivity(intent);

Comment: @imtiazeemel Sorry, i was wrong. Try new code from my answer

Comment: @imtiazeemel I edit answer again. Now it works, i checked with your project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235765/discussion-between-imtiaz-eemel-and-leonid).